# Do SingleValueEvent listeners count towards 'simultaneous connections' in Firebase RealTime DB until explicitly removed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As per the Firebase docs, listeners added through addListenerForSingleValueEvent() trigger once returning all the data incuding child nodes at the reference on which it is added and then does not trigger again. Now with any listeners attached to a reference, the Db connection is counted as being in use.

Once the single value listener triggers, 
does it automatically release the database connection unlike other child event listeners or value event listeners ?
OR
does it continue to get counted as a database connection under the simultaneous connection limit unless explicitly removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listening for a single event is exactly the same as adding a normal listener. The SDK just removes that listener after the first time it's triggered.

Removing the last listener doesn't necessarily "release" the connection immediately.  As an optimization, the connection will stick around for a while, then get dropped due to a lack of listeners.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer Frank and Doug. So that infers there is no need to explicitly detach this listener using removeEventListener() or is it a best practice to remove this listener explicitly in onDestroy() in case the activity gets destroyed before the event gets triggered?

Comment: This is a whole different issue than connection management.  You should remove all listeners when you no longer need them.  It isn't aware of the scope of the activity, so if you leave it on when the activity goes away, it still might trigger and cause a crash when trying to refer to something that no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks Doug got it. So in my case, as I am using the data returned by the single value event listener only within the same activity, it would be best practice to remove the listener in onDestroy() to avoid such a crash.

Comment: That's one way to do it.  Everyone may have different requirements for when to add and remove.